# Count duplicate rows only based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates, having

assume i have the following table named `test` with 2 columns `A` and `B` 
`A    B`

`------`

 `1    2`

 `2    3`

 `1    2`

 `3    4`
I would like to use a query that would return only the count of duplicate rows (1 and 3 in this case) based on columns `A` and `B` combined, so the count returned should be `2`.
`SELECT 'Duplicates' As Warning, count(*) AS RowCount FROM test where`(query goes here) , thanks.

Comment: if there are multiple duplicate rows, like (1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(2,3)? what is ur expected result?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(*) as Count FROM Test GROUP BY A, B HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I am getting the following error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: maybe alias as rowCount2 instead of as Count... the rest should work. The error you indicate seems to mean that you need to do count(colName) > 1 but that is unlikely...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, if there had been another row in your example (2,3) then the count should be 4. If that so, use this:

```
SELECT 'Duplicates' as warning,sum(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT a,b,COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY a,b
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get as pair use,

```
SELECT CONCAT(A,'-',B) AS Duplicate Pair,COUNT(A) AS COUNT FROM `test` GROUP BY A,B HAVING COUNT(A) > 1;
```

OR
To get as individual use,

```
SELECT A AS Duplicate1,B AS Duplicate2,COUNT(A) AS COUNT FROM `test` GROUP BY A,B HAVING COUNT(A) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
select 'Duplicates' as warning, count(*) as rowcount
from (select a, b, count(*) as cnt
      from test t
      group by a, b
      having cnt > 1
     ) t;
```

Comment: you need to add the HAVING clause in your subquery (see my answer above) for it to filter properly, OR add a where clause after (where t.count > 1)).